# JSON parsing after protocols

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I implemented a carousel with a collection view. I want to parse a JSON data into it, but the JSON parses after the necessary protocols. Because of this the array is empty when i try to configure the cells.

I know the problem occurs when I try to reload the data. When I do this in a table view controller I can just call tableView.reloadData() but I can't do this in the normal view controller I use.

```
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

This is the order when i print it:
loadjson
numberofsections
cellforitemat
cellforitemat
parsejson

Comment: `UICollectionView` has the same method as `UITableView`: `collectionView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I do this in a table view controller I can just call tableView.reloadData() but I can't do this in the normal view controller

in normal vc you should have a property like

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView:UICollectionView!
```

and reload it when needed unlike the collection controller which encapsulates that property by default

---

Regrading the order of getting the data is asynchronous so check this [CollectionView not display data after parsing JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56589332/collectionview-not-display-data-after-parsing-json) for a similar case

---

These 2 lines

```
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

are totally irrelevant , they used for refreshing the UI and constraints

Comment: Thanks! Now i feel really stupid that I didn't think of that... I am new to swift but love to learn